# Trouble applying background color to span::after pseudo-element in Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have a radio button component styled with Tailwind CSS. I'm currently facing an issue where I need to select the ::after pseudo-element of a child element of a sibling element of the radio input within my component.

```js
import React, {HTMLProps} from 'react';
import {twMerge} from "tailwind-merge";

const Radio: React.FC<{ className?: string } & HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement>> = ({className = '', ...props}) => {
    return (
        <div className='w-full'>
            <input
                {...props}
                className={twMerge('peer', className)}
                type='radio'
            />
            <label className='cursor-pointer text-base flex gap-4 peer-checked:[&>span:after]:bg-primary' htmlFor={props.id}>
                <span className='h-7 w-7 rounded-full border-4 border-primary block
                flex items-center justify-center
                    after:block after:w-3.5 after:h-3.5 after:bg-primary after:rounded-full after:opacity-0
                '/>
                {props.label}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Radio;
```

unfortunately this code doesn't work, but when I write it like this

```
peer-checked:[&>span]:bg-primary
```

it completely works but when I write it like below

```
peer-checked:[&>span:after]:bg-primary
```

it doesn't work anymore I don't know how I can access to this after psudo

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `after:opacity-0` class on your span element which makes the `span::after` pseudo-element invisible. You can use the following class on the `label` element to make the `span::after` visible when the radio button is checked.

```
peer-checked:[&>span:after]:opacity-100
```